# Disabling intellisense sugestions for specific packages?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellisense

Is it possible to disable certain intellisense suggestions from certain packages on a per project level? Let's say I want to create a JavaFX application, it is not desirable to have all these similarly named classes pop up suggestions in intellisense for like AWT, JavaX or any other integrated package. So in this case I would like to disable AWT and JavaX from showing up in intellisense suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import | Exclude from Import and Completion. You can also press Alt+Enter in the code completion popup (or Right in the auto-import popup) and exclude the items from there.